# Available update icon is shown, but no update is found

Tags: windows-10, updates

The windows show the icon that say that there is an update, and my version will reach end of service soon. But when I'm trying to update from the settings, no available update was found. Restart didn't help. (Right now I'm using version 1909)

Thanx for help.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of this icon?  There are hardware configurations that block 2004 which means, if you have that particular hardware, you will have to wait for that block to be lifted.  You have over 2 months before your version (1909) actually is retired.  Microsoft will either extend that date due the hardware configuration block or resolve it before that date.  Without knowing if the feature update is being blocked this question cannot actually be answered (IMO)

Comment: I suspect I know what icon, but I want to verify, that we are talking about the same icon.

Answer (score 0):

Find an empty USB flash drive, at least 8 GB. Use it to [create a Windows installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). It will be about 5 GB download.

Once the USB is prepared, open it and run `setup.exe`. It will guide you through the upgrade process. The default settings don't cause any data loss, just like regular Windows Update. You can also choose to install from scratch if you wish.

As always with large updates, you should first make sure your backups are up to date and restorable.

Comment: It’s unnecessary to use a flash drive, the author could simply mount the 20H2 ISO and perform the upgrade, running the setup.exe from a flash drive or a mounted ISO is an identical upgrade action

Comment: @Ramhound Interesting, does the setup extract all data onto the system drive before reboot?

Comment: It works exactly the way it would work if the feature update was downloaded by Windows Update, Upgrade Assistant, or Media Creation Tool.  I have not really thought about it, other than use it hundreds of times, without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** there are so many combinations of computers and drivers that not all computers are ready to be updated. If that is the case here, then wait for Windows to do the update on its own.

That is the preferred approach, all other things being equal. You can wait for a bit, say until the next Patch Tuesday (April, 2021)

**Second:**  If you wish to start the update, then you can use the Microsoft Media Creation Link and use the first selection: Upgrade my computer.

[Media Creation Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

Comment: OP's at version 1909 - two (soon three) versions behind almost out of support. It's very, very unlikely that MS is still preparing an update for them.

Comment: I understand but Patch Tuesday comes soon and then use the second approach above.

Comment: @gronostaj - 1909 is support until May 2021.  This means it still receives security updates until that date.

Comment: @Ramhound What I meant is that indeed sometimes feature updates are held to fix compatibility issues with particular hardware, but they wouldn't be held for over two feature updates.

Comment: @gronostaj - Except 2004 and 20H2 are essentially the same update.  Microsoft wouldn't push 2004 to 1909 machines since they will have the same compatibility issues.  20H2 is enabled through an enablement package, the same is true, for 1909.